# How to read the child node in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I have a Firebase Realtime Database and I want to write to it, that's simple enough, but I have added more than one tree to my Database and want to know how to write to the second tree. Right now I can only write to the first tree.

Image for better understanding:
[image]

So for example how can I write to the Color info.

Note: The first line of string (User line in image) is the users id token (currentFirebaseUser.uid) //uid = User ID and the second line of string(Info line in image) is automatically generated by firebase

Database code:

```
  _getDBRides() {
    return Expanded(
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: dbRef,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, DataSnapshot snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          Map Rides = snapshot.value as Map;
          //unique key/id of each item in db
          Rides['key'] = snapshot.key;
          return listItem(Rides: Rides);
        },
      ),
    );
  }`
```

```
Button(
  onTap: () {
    if (_validateDate() == true) {
      ref.child('Rides/${user.uid}').push().set({
        //Info saved in database
      }).asStream();
      _titleController.clear();
    }
  },
),
```

If there is one tree in the database then I can reference it like this

```
Rides['Color']
```

But because there is another tree I don't know how to write to it

What I have tried: `Rides['key']['Color']` doesn't work

Seems short but I have tried writing it in different ways too to see how to write to that tree but nothing work and the documentation doesn't seem to show how to write to a second tree.

Comment: You seem to be asking about writing data, yet none of your code writes to the database. Can you show how you currently write the data, what output you get in the database from that, and what output you want instead?

Comment: I'm asking how can I retrieve the data form the database, not write to it, apologies for my unclear questions. I have also added the code where I write to the database

Comment: "How to **write** to second tree in Firebase Realtime Database" and "Seems short but I have tried **writing** it in different ways too to see how to **write** to that tree but nothing work and the documentation doesn't seem to show how to **write** to a second tree." ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: okay thats mb, but do you know how to get the info from the database

Comment: Can you please update the question so it more aligns with what's being asked? It's important questions be accurate so future readers will be able to find it. e.g. if a reader is looking how to *read firebase* your question will not appear because it talks about *writing*, not *reading*. Also, the question mentions *tree* and we don't know what that means exactly. For example, in the question `Rides` is a parent node, and the item scribbled out underneath it is a child node (etc etc). Are you asking how to *read* the Color node?

Comment: Yes!, I will delete this question and make a new one, but yes that is what im asking how can i read the color node!

Comment: Usually when there was only one child node, then I could just write Rides['Color'] but now the child node has a child node and I dont know how I can read for example the color anymore

Comment: How is `dbRef` initialized? And if there are multiple children for each `DataSnapshot`, what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: I made a new question where I answer both those questions but it got closed, Im going to delete all these questions and start fresh, i think my communication was bad, im going to improve

Comment: We would encourage you to update your question so it's more clear. I kind of understand what's being asked but the context is not clear (write vs read). I also noticed this *second line of string(Info line in image) is automatically generated by firebase* - since you know the db node, and the user node, what's preventing you from querying the user node for all child nodes that contain the color you're looking for? Maybe that's not what you're asking?

Comment: I do not know how to querying the user node for all child nodes

Comment: ok, We can help but the question needs to ask what is intended. At the moment it says - *I want to write to it* - and - *I can only write to the first tree* - as well as - *how can I write to the Color info* -. Reading and Writing are different tasks and would require different code so. You can either attempt to update *this* question or create a new question that clearly states your intention (advised)

Comment: I am going to delete the question and start over, but I am very busy so I'm probably going to make the question in a couple of days